# m2e - Cannot Resolve Dependency Type of 'pom'

Tags: eclipse, maven, grails, m2e, spring-tool-suite

I have a grails project that uses maven and am trying to run it in Spring Tool Suite.  In BuildConfig.groovy the following is set:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
   pom true
   ...
}
```

In the pom file this is in the dependencies section:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
    <artifactId>grails-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Building in maven and in grails works fine, no issues there, but when I try to import the project as a maven project in STS, I get this error:

```
Archive for required library: '~/.m2/repository/org/grails/grails-dependencies/2.4.5/grails-dependencies-2.4.5.pom' in project 'my-project' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file
```

Trying to import it as a Grails project (and not maven) doesn't resolve any of the dependencies. I really don't want to have to list every dependency in grails-dependencies-2.4.5.pom in my project pom, so I was wondering if anyone else has seen this?

Comment: What do you want to achieve by adding the *org.grails:grails-dependencies:2.4.5:pom* artifact to the dependency section?

Answer (score 0):

From your pom.xml declaration, it is evident that you are also using bill of material (bom) concept. Try using following declaration in your pom.xml file.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
            <artifactId>grails-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Add your grail dependencies -->
</dependencies>
```